# python 3 will not find key in dict from msgpack

Tags: python-3.x, msgpack

why does this happen in python3?

1) I get msgpack data from redis

2) I unpack I get the below

3) The returned type is a dict:

```
meta = msgpack.unpackb(data[1])
print(type(meta))
<class 'dict'>

 meta = {b'api_key': b'apikey1',
        b'sensor_id': b'sid1',
        b'version': b'1.0'}
```

If I run the below: 
     sensor_meta['sensor_id']

```
{b'api_key': b'apikey1',
 b'sensor_id': b'sid1',
 b'version': b'1.0'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//worker.py", line 247, in <module>
    print(meta['sensor_id'])
KeyError: 'sensor_id'
```

but if I use sensor_meta[b'sensor_id'] then it works.

What is the "b" and how can i get rid of that?  How do I convert the whole object so there are no b's ?

so if I do the below:

```
   print(type(meta['sensor_id']))
   <class 'bytes'>
```

why bytes and how did it get there?  I do not to append a b for every time I want to use keys in a hash.

Thanks

Comment: can you add information for `data[1]` as well

Comment: irrelevant...data[1] is the data I want to unpack and is listed

Comment: but I formally defined meta

Comment: what type of data do you have in `data[1]`?

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the notes [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack-python):

> string and binary type In old days, msgpack doesn’t distinguish string
>   and binary types like Python 1. The type for represent string and
>   binary types is named raw.
>
> msgpack can distinguish string and binary type for now. But it is not
>   like Python 2. Python 2 added unicode string. But msgpack renamed raw
>   to str and added bin type. It is because keep compatibility with data
>   created by old libs. raw was used for text more than binary.
>
> Currently, while msgpack-python supports new bin type, default setting
>   doesn’t use it and decodes raw as bytes instead of unicode (str in
>   Python 3).
>
> You can change this by using use_bin_type=True option in Packer and
>   encoding=”utf-8” option in Unpacker.

```
>>> import msgpack
>>> packed = msgpack.packb([b'spam', u'egg'], use_bin_type=True)
>>> msgpack.unpackb(packed, encoding='utf-8') ['spam', u'egg']
```

You can define an encoding while unpacking to  convert your bytes to strings.

```
msgpack.unpackb(data[1], encoding='utf-8')
```