# Decoding msgpack_numpy with utf-8 strings

Tags: python, numpy, encoding, utf-8, msgpack

I use python 3.6 with `msgpack==0.5.1` and `msgpack_numpy==0.4.2`.

When trying to encode and decode a `dict`, the string [needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319949/msgpack-unserialising-dict-key-strings-to-bytes) to be handled using `utf-8` to restore the dict's keys as strings (instead of binaries).

For example:

```
import msgpack

d = {'key': None}
binary = msgpack.packb(d)

ret = msgpack.unpackb(binary)
ret.keys()
>>> dict_keys([b'key'])

ret = msgpack.unpackb(binary, encoding='utf-8')
ret.keys()
>>> dict_keys(['key'])
```

However, when using `msgpack_numpy`, passing `encoding='utf-8'` brakes the `numpy` decoding:

```
import numpy as np
import msgpack_numpy as m
m.patch()

d['key'] = np.arange(5)
binary = msgpack.packb(d)

ret = msgpack.unpackb(binary)
ret.keys()
>>> dict_keys([b'key'])
ret[b'key']
>>> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

ret = msgpack.unpackb(binary, encoding='utf-8')
ret.keys()
>>> dict_keys(['key'])
ret['key']
>>> {'data': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'kind': '', 'nd': True, 'shape': [5], 'type': '<i8'}
```

Is it possible to encode/decode `numpy` arrays using `msgpack` without replacing the dict's keys to binary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fiddled with different packing options and discovered that using `use_bin_type=True` when packing the object solves the problem.

```
import msgpack
import numpy as np
import msgpack_numpy as m
m.patch()

d = {'key': np.arange(5)}
binary = msgpack.packb(d, use_bin_type=True)

ret = msgpack.unpackb(binary, encoding='utf-8')
ret.keys()
>>> dict_keys(['key'])
ret['key']
>>> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: that worked for me too! some extra info on that: https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python/issues/270 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46960419/python-3-will-not-find-key-in-dict-from-msgpack